# frequency wavenumber plot python

Tags: imshow

I have a csv file that contains 62503 rows and 513 columns,each column is a different position and the all the rows at that column represent the time signal.
i need to plot the frequency wave number representation using imshow. i have used the fft2 directly on the data but i didn't get anything, i don't know if i have to write a loop but i am not that familiar with it.
can you help me please.
Thanks`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.fftpack
import pylab as py
from scipy import misc, fftpack
from scipy.fftpack import fft,ifft,fft2,fftshift

df=pd.read_csv('/home/sarah/Documents/data/data7/myline2.csv', delimiter=',',header=None)

x= df.iloc[0]  #the positions
y = np.linspace(0.000000016,0.000008208,513)  #time vector

data=df.iloc[3:62503,0:513]     # matrix of amplitudes 


plt.imshow(data, aspect='auto', interpolation='none',extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()] , cmap= 'seismic') # this to plot a B-scan(amplitude plot with respect to position and time) and it works perfectly.

x,y= np.meshgrid(x, y)

plt.figure(1)

plt.savefig('my2lineshow.png')

plt.figure(2)

z=fft2(data)  # i tried this to switch from the time/position domain to the frequency/wavenumber domain without actually switching the axes too.
plt.imshow(abs(z), aspect='auto', interpolation='none', cmap= 'seismic')

plt.savefig('fft2.png')

plt.show()` # it showed an empty figure!
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot to explain:

Comment: y is the time vector, and x the positions (the first row), the data represents the amplitudes, i didn't know how to convert the x to the wave number and t to frequency to show them in the x,y axes at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to SO @t.sarah, please edit your question and paste the explanation into it.